# Receiving external JSON data via PHP

Tags: php, json

I`m trying to receive a external json file via PHP.

I'm trying this way:

```
<?php

$json_file = file_get_contents("http://www.moonwalk.com.br/api/VitrineDeProdutos/58e903df295cbc5c4639434d4c35090d");

$json_str = json_decode($json_file, true);

$itens = $json_str->nodes;

foreach ( $itens as $e ) 
    { echo "$e->title<br>"; } 
?>
```

But, its is not working.

The external file is in:
http://www.moonwalk.com.br/api/VitrineDeProdutos/58e903df295cbc5c4639434d4c35090d

Can anyone help me? What i'm doing wrong?

Really thanks!

Comment: JSON data is valid... Which error do you get? Please, more details.

Answer (score 1):

`$json_str` is an array not an object as you explicitly asked for casting via `json_decode($json_file, true)`.

```
$itens = $json_str['nodes'];
```

and same goes for `$e`

```
foreach ($itens as $e) {
    echo $e['title'] . "<br>";
}
```

If you want to use your code as is just remove argument from `json_decode($json_file);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
$json_file = file_get_contents("http://www.moonwalk.com.br/api/VitrineDeProdutos/58e903df295cbc5c4639434d4c35090d");

$json_str = json_decode($json_file, true);

if (!empty($json_str['nodes'])) {
    foreach ($json_str['nodes'] as $e) {
        echo $e['title'] . "<br>";
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try
check the php settings...

it may be due to security issue... "**allow_url_fopen = On"**

set it **php.ini**

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Answer (score 0):

Go the other way around. You *receive* a JSON-formatted string. Are you sure it is not

`nodes`->`children`->`title` you want?

```php
$json_file = file_get_contents("http://www.moonwalk.com.br/api/VitrineDeProdutos/58e903df295cbc5c4639434d4c35090d");
$json_array = json_decode($json_file, true);
foreach ($json_array['nodes'][0]['children'] as $node) { 
    echo $node['title'].'<br>'; 
}
```

outputs :

```
Monte Seu Mix
Mix - 18 peças
Mix - 20 peças
Mix - 30 peças
Mix - 49 peças
Mix - 70 peças
Salmão ou Atum na crosta - 15 peças
Salmão ou Atum selados - 15 peças
Guiosa de frango - 5 unidades
Yakisoba Camarão ou Frutos do Mar
Yakissoba Carne ou Frango
Teppan Yaki
Hot Tradicional
Hot com Camarão à milanesa
```